# Unix HP-UX ksh recursive find and replace

Tags: unix, sed, ksh, hp-ux

I am trying to do a recursive find and replace in HP-UX and am missing something.

What I have at the moment:

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

I know the problem is that it's not replacing the file inline. I believe on other OS's there is a -i flag, but it seems in my HP-UX version, there isn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In-place editing for `sed` is not POSIX, which explains why it's not available for you. You could try Perl instead if it's available, since Perl has a `-i` option that does the same. http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/ has some info. Just don't blindly try something without backup!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Using perl was the way that worked for me: find . -name "*.java" | xargs perl -pi -e's/foo/bar/g'

Comment: Also asked on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14278552/7552

Comment: just take out the xargs and leave the sed.

Answer (score 1):

you could workaround the missing `-i` like this (untested):

```
for i in `find . -name "*.java"`; do cp $i /tmp/$$; sed 's/foo/bar/g' < /tmp/$$ > $i;done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `ed`

```
find . -name "*.java" | while IFS= read -r file; do
  ed "$file" <<ED_COMMANDS
%s/foo/bar/g
w
q
ED_COMMANDS
done
```